# Access denied to file in sites/all/default/files

Tags: files

I am getting:

```
access denied   04/30/2013 - 16:56  sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/KRIS... admin
```

in my error message log when trying to do some file updating. I am guessing this is a permissions problem, but i am running on a local server. How do I change permissions in drupal for access to read/write to the files folder on a mac in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was `$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;` in the settings.php file. An update from drupal 7.20.

Comment: You saved my time +1. I wonder why it has to be so difficult to deal with version upgrades!

Comment: can you explain a bit more? that line should be there or not there?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal.org has a great guide on [permissions](http://drupal.org/node/244924).

**The TLDR; version.**

You can change permissions by opening up your terminal and perform the following commmand:

`(sudo) chmod <mode> <path>`.

For more information about `chmod`, check the [manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html). Or just perform:

`chmod --help`

Answer (score 0):

you should give permissions to it using

sudo chmod 777 sites/all/default/files

This would remove the problem of permissions and would give rights for read, write and execute  permission to the files folder.