# Access denied to sites/default/files/styles/slide when adding items to mediabox field

Tags: 7, media, files

I have a field called field_property_slideshow which is type of [mediabox](https://drupal.org/project/mediabox) to add image gallery to a node. This was working fine until last week (may be after the updates). I am breaking my head to resolve this issue since a week time. My issue is exactly same or similar to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71706/access-denied-to-file-in-sites-all-default-files) issue. I tried the solutions given this issue but I did not get the luck.

- According the accepted solution I added
  `$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;` in the
- settings.php Also according to another solution I changed
  `sites/default/files/styles/slide/public` folder permission to 777

  - To give more information this folders owner is ftpuser (is user name and group name) who is owner of this folder and www-data is this group member
- I replaced the module files with the older version from the backup but it gives me same problem. The same thing works on my wamp environment

This is my error log

```
Type        page not found
Location    http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/slide/public/?itok=EO40h_nX 
Referrer    http://www.mysite.com/node/115/edit
Message     sites/default/files/styles/slide/public
```

Comment: Does file exist in that folder? Did you check it?

Comment: Try to check the permissions of the parent folders (sites/default/files/, sites/default/files/styles/ ...). Try a `chmod -R 777 sites/default/files` and see if it fixes your problem. If yes, try to narrow it down so you don't have security issues.